# Class alias vs Variable class name

Tags: php, class, variables, registry, alias

I'm creating my own PHP framework (for the learning experience), and I can't decide which of these would be a better practice.

1. Create a Registry class that has the name of every class. Other classes will call the registry to find the class name.
2. Create an AliasRegistry class that will create aliases for every class.

When accessing a class name with the first design, my code will look like this:

```
    $delegateClass = $this->registry->delegate;
    $object = new $delegateClass;
```

When accessing a class with the second design, my code will look like this:

```
    $object = new _NI_ALIAS;
```

It will also allow me to dynamically extend other classes and implement interfaces

```
    class Template implements _NI_ALIAS
```

The second one makes a lot more sense to me, especially since I can just include it in the framework's namespace; but for some reason, I see people labeling this as pad practice, since it can affect things globally.

Which would you say is a better practice?

Comment: Why not just set up spl_autoload, and autoload each class on request and use that instead of jumping through these hoops?

Comment: Why a registry for this? Wouldn't using `new nameoftheclass()` be easier?

Comment: I'd say the best practice is neither of what it is you're considering. Try looking into existing frameworks, and see how they do things...

Comment: I wanted to be able to dynamically change a class in one central location. Say I have an EventHandler class that a lot of other classes depend on, and somebody wants to 'import' a different one; instead of deleting the original, they can just specify a new class and use the same alias.

Comment: @AddisonBurns you mean like `use \namespace\someClass as AliasClassName`?

Comment: Also in your last example, `class Template implements _NI_ALIAS` - If `_NI_ALIAS` is a constant variable you will get a fatal error

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem Sorry for the ambiguity; I meant class_alias ('\namespace\class','AliasName'), but I guess they achieve the same outcome. The point of controlling everything with a registry was to supervise the aliases and make sure there were no duplicates. EDIT: It would also stop me from having to edit each individual file.

Comment: @AlexP Very true. Good point. I could always do a check with defined () when adding a new alias to the registry.... Though, I realize that's a lot of overhead for not much gain. I'm probably just over-thinking things.

Comment: @AddisonBurns: You're missing the point: PHP won't eval `implements _NI_ALIAS` to `implements someInterface`, but it'll look for the `_NI_ALIAS` interface definition... it's regarded as a string literal, not a constant

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem That part's not true... If you register an interface with class_alias ('MyInterFace','ALIAS'), then try to implement it (MyClass implements ALIAS), it will know ALIAS is an alias and search for 'MyInterface'.

Comment: @AddisonBurns: I'm talking about that part of your question where you want to _dynamically extend a class_, using a variable interface name... that won't work. Also, your design will be a _nightmare_ when using type-hinting (which you should, that's good practice)

Comment: class A
{
 public function __construct ()
 {
  echo 'Hello';
 }
}

class_alias ('A','ALIAS');

class B extends ALIAS
{
 public function __construct ()
 {
  parent::__construct ();
  echo ' World';
 }
}

new B;

Comment: I just tested that and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AddisonBurns: You're missing my point completely... sure that might work. But by using all caps, it looked as though you were using a constant. The issue that remains is: what if there is no class_alias set? you'll get an error, unless the alias you're using is a default class, in which case you'll have a name conflict whenever the user wants to change the parent class... _That's bad practice_

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative; I appreciate the input, but earlier you were saying I missed the point because PHP can't eval that. Now the point is that even though it can eval that, I shouldn't do it. I am not missing the point; the point keeps changing. Anyway, I appreciate the criticism of it. I'll definitely take something away from the discussion.

Comment: @AddisonBurns: Ok, there was a fundamental misunderstanding at work here, it seems. Because your alias (in the example) was an all-caps string, I assumed it was a constant (like convention dictates constants look). As it turned out, that assumption was wrong - nevertheless: by allowing users of your framework to change the inheritance structure of your classes, you're entering a world of trouble in terms of type hinting and, as I explained in my previous comment, the inevitable name conflict... sorry if I came across as some fighty arrogant jerk... ;-)